# Adjust scheduling query outputs to follow set rules

Tags: sql-server, loops, while-loop

How do I evaluate a subsequent row based on the prior row in the same column.

I have a scheduling query with times that need to be adjusted based on several conditions.

For simplicity assume each row in the base output contains schedule times in hours.

> Sch 
>   1 
>   2 
>   4 
>   6 
>   6 
>   8

I need to adjust the outputs to follow set rules, such as minimum 2 hr spacing. My results should be:

> Sch  ....... Adj Sch
>   1.............     1
>   2.............     3
>   4.............     5
>   6.............     7
>   6.............     9
>   8............     11

I'm assuming I have to loop through the table but not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

`WHILE` loops are generally frowned upon in SQL Server. You can also choose to use a `CURSOR`. Since you asked about how to do loops in SQL here is the basic concept:

```
DECLARE @counter as int
SET @Counter = 0
--Do something here to each row
WHILE @Counter < someNumberOrCountFromTheDatabase

BEGIN

SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END
```

Make sure you have your logic correctly thought out or you risk going in an endless loop.

Here is a [good SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027477/cursors-vs-while-loop-sqlserver) explaining the difference between CURSOR, LOOPS and possibly using a recursive CTE.

Comment: Note that cursors are *also* generally frowned upon.

Comment: But cursors are still slightly better than good old fashioned WHILE loops